# Loop for a dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a question for a possible loop. Maybe there is another solution for the problem?

Here the example of my dataframe:

[image: Dataframe example]

I want to count the values in column **"to count"**(always 1) 
if the values in column **"id"** are the same and write the result in column **"solution?"**

After that i can delete column "z" and do "unique"

I think it`s not too hard, but i do not find the right command + I got my Problems with loops :-(

Thanks for help!

Comment: In the future, please don't share your data as screenshots. It's useless that way for testing code. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1412059) to learn better ways of sharing data.

Comment: @Roland , Thanks a lot for helping me out. You saved me Weekend ! I will consider the FAQ next time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in one step:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(DF, .(id, x, y), summarise, sumcount=sum(to_count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ddply` from plyr package [Assume `mydata` is your data)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(id),transform, solution=length(id))
```